# Present perfect simple tense in conditionals

Tags: tense, present-perfect, conditional-constructions, present-simple

The present perfect tense is used in the sentence below but  [here](https://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/conditional/) and [here](https://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/how-use-unless/), they do not use the present perfect. Can we use present perfect simple tense in conditional sentences like the sentence below? If so, what is difference between *has finished* and *finishes*?

> Unless a probationary employee *has* successfully *finished* the training, he cannot be considered a full employee and be assigned to one of the teams.

Comment: You need to speak about either *the following sentence* or *the sentence below* but you can't use *the below sentence* or *the belows sentence*. These constructions are not grammatical.

Answer (score 2):

In conditionals like this, there is no difference between using *finishes* and *has finished*. You can use either of them and there is no semantic difference whatsoever.  Which one you choose is a matter of taste.

Personally, *has finished* sounds better to me though.

Comment: Is it conditional on the verb that *has finished* is more to your taste than *finishes*?

Comment: Not particularly, it's mostly context. Also, I can totally imagine another person preferring *finishes* in the same situation.

Comment: Actually, there's a situation where *finishes* becomes better. If the thing definitely hasn't happened yet (and thus will happen in the future), then *finishes* is more appropriate. *"Unless he finishes his exam, I can't grade it"*

Comment: Then in my question, an employee is training now and not yet done, right?

Comment: @Orient If it's guaranteed that the the training hasn't been finished yet, then I would prefer *finishes* (and I would also pair it with *until* instead of *unless*). However, I assume there are employees in your company that *have* finished the training and are thus considered 'full employees'.